# Does Magento use PHPMailer to handle/send emails?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

Recently a critical remote code execution vulnerability in PHPMailer has been discovered, and that has been reported on https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2016/12/phpmailer-vulnerability/?utm_source=list&utm_campaign=122816&utm_medium=email which focuses on WordPress sites.

However I'd like to know if this can affect somehow Magento installations as well or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses [Zend\Mail](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html) by default. Magento is built upon the Zend framework, and as such uses many of its components.

So, in short, this PHPMailer vulnerability doesn't apply to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use PHP mailer with Magento

Refer : http://www.mrmagento.com/magento/mag-send-mimehtml-emails-with-php-mailer/

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am talking about vanilla installation of Magento. Do you mean that Magento uses PHPMailer by default?

Comment: Nope it does not use it by default. But you can use it manually. Refer the above link